# what's the meaning of vscode `Open folder before change configurations`

Tags: visual-studio-code

Each time when I open my vscode it shows `Open folder before change configurations`

[image]

What's the meaning of it and how can I hidden this message?

My OS Version: MacOS-10.13.3 and vscode version:1.19.3

**UPDATE**

I just found that message is from the extension `vscode-database`, but I still don't know what it means. Is anyone knows what it mean? Do I have to create a database configure file first ?

[image]

Comment: Is that happening after any extension installation?

Comment: @Ferus7 Yes, I just found that message is from the extension `vscode-database`

Comment: So I guess that is just an advertisement, because `vscode-database` uses the current opened folder

Comment: @Ferus7 I see, thanks.

Comment: Same for me, I filed an issue on the extensions repo: https://github.com/Bajdzis/vscode-database/issues/37  Worth noting when I disable vscode-database the info no longer happens.

Comment: I had the same issue with the C/Cpp extension. I saw the error when I attempted to `Edit Configurations`. To fix it I had to open the folder which the source file I was working on was located. Doing this fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this occurs when I open in vs code only .c file. After this error, I use an *File -> open folder* option where was .c file stored. For me then vs code generates configurations JSON in this folder, which I need to edit